# How to make single graphical plot from 3

Tags: r, plot, merge

How to build a single graphical plot (with the line plot - each account should be a different color..) so it will show how the balance changed for all 3 accounts during the year in one graphical ? I tried already everything, no idea about it..

```
   time        account_a    account_b      account_c
1  2016-01-01  2919.446     7774.078       1042.3338
2  2016-02-01  2649.327     7810.399       436.1774
```

So far i used this code:

```
plot(abc$account_a,col="red")
plot(abc$account_b,col="blue")
plot(abc$account_c,col="green")
```

and now how to merge each of them to get an single graphic?

Comment: Before plot use `par(mfrow = c(1, 3))`

Comment: if by merge you mean combine the lines, use `plot(abc$account_a,col="red")` followed by a couple of `lines(abc$account_b,col="blue")` to add the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(abc) + 
  geom_line(aes(time, account_a), col = "red")) + 
  geom_line(aes(time, account_b), col = "blue")) + 
  geom_line(aes(time, account_c), col = "green"))
```